# Stream Binary data to javascript html from Java ServerSocket

Tags: javascript, java, html, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to stream binary data, to Html page using java Server built using ServerSocket. Able to achieve this using xmlhttprequest, but observing a big delay in receiving end. Please share the better way to do the same to avoid delay. Also built WebSocket Server using java but not able to receive data as binary in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you didn't specify content length of you binary stream and/or not close servlet output stream. Please consider the following code

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException {
       byte[] binaryData = createBinaryContent();
       OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
       response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
       response.setContentLength(binaryData.length);
       out.write(binaryData);
       out.close();
    }
```

Comment: Getting string type in websocket even after sending content type as specified by you

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Please try response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")

Comment: And response.setContentLength(binaryData.length)